# SqlGeography STIntersect returns always false

Tags: c#, sql-server, geospatial

I have a problem here with this function. I'm trying to detect in Bing Maps AJAX if a point is inside a polygon. Since the Bing maps v7 API doesn't have any function to check that, I was forced to build my own code. In theory, everything is correct, but always return false. Any ideas? I'm missing something? Here is my code,

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;

...

[WebMethod]
public static bool PointIntersectPolygon(string PoiLat, string PoiLng, string[] PolyArr)
{
    SqlGeography Point;
    SqlGeography PolyGeo;
    string PolyStr = "", LatStr = "", LngStr = "";

    int Cnt=0;
    while(Cnt < PolyArr.Length) {
        LatStr = PolyArr[Cnt];
        LngStr = PolyArr[Cnt + 1];
        PolyStr = PolyStr + LngStr + " " + LatStr;

        Cnt=Cnt+2;
        if (Cnt < PolyArr.Length) { PolyStr = PolyStr + ", "; }
    }

    //Point = SqlGeography.STPointFromText(new SqlChars("point(" + PoiLng + " " + PoiLat + ")"), 4326);
    //PolyGeo = SqlGeography.STPolyFromText(new SqlChars("polygon((" + PolyStr + "))"), 4326);

    Point = SqlGeography.STPointFromText(new SqlChars("point(-95.2267532349 29.6912727356)"), 4326);
    PolyGeo = SqlGeography.STPolyFromText(new SqlChars("polygon((-95.8686820418 30.0354040414, -95.1099929810 30.1058311462, -95.0110397339 29.5988826752, -95.5437927246 29.5567703247, -95.8686820418 30.0354040414))"), 4326);
    MessageBox.Show(PolyGeo.STContains(Point).ToString());

    bool PolyPoi = (bool)PolyGeo.STContains(Point);
    return PolyPoi;
}
```

I commented out some lines, and put hard coded values to check, And I still have the same result. I'm pretty sure the point in inside the polygon.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between a clockwise polygon and a counter-clockwise polygon?

Comment: @ErikPhilips if you check the values, the points in the polygon are clockwise.

Comment: [Then it's backwards](http://jasonfollas.com/blog/post/2008/11/25/sqlgeography-ring-orientation-of-polygon-interior-rings-holes.aspx).  Inclusive is Counter-Clockwise.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thanks for the information, and for the downvote. I appreciate the fact you provided me the information, but I think SO is about teaching beginner users (like me), not about punishment if the user don't find the information in an easy way. I'm not an C# developer, and I have a entire week trying to seek information about C# and Bing Maps. And, as you can already know, the information on Bing Maps API is more limited compared with Google.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't downvote you.  99% of the time I don't help downvoted question, because in my own opinion, they aren't good questions.

Comment: @ErikPhilips then my apologize for you, and thanks again.

Comment: If that solved the problem, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Server geography types uses the left-hand approach.  That is as you create polygon, whatever is to the left as you enclose the polygon is the *inside* of the polygon.

You can read more: [SqlGeography: Ring Orientation of Polygons](http://jasonfollas.com/blog/post/2008/11/24/spatial-determining-ring-orientation.aspx)